# X1 Carbon laptop driver crash

Tags: windows-10, drivers, crash, lenovo-laptop, reinstall

After my X1 Carbon 3rd Gen laptop became infested with adware i decided to reinstall Windows 10. Problem is that with the new Windows 10 installation, I can't install any drivers on the computer except for the ones installed by Windows Update.

Here are some examples of what happens after installing drivers from for example Lenovos site:

1. I reboot the computer after driver install, and is met by the screen: "Missing operating system". Rebooting again usually leads to number 2 or 3:
2. Computer reboots normally. After a period of time, a program (for example Firefox) doesn't respond, and seconds later my screen becomes black execpt for the taskbar. Then the blue screen: "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you..." comes up, which leads to number 3.
3. After reboot Windows tries to repair the system, but seems to fail before finishing: "Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC".

I'm using the laptop right now and it seems to be working fine, since i haven't installed any drivers except the ones from Windows Update. The computer has been rebooted 10+ times, and all programs works normally. I could potentially use the laptop now as I normally would, but avoiding installing drivers isn't optimal. I would prefer to find a solution to this problem.

**Further information**

First time i installed drivers after reinstall, was through Lenovo's website where it analysed my laptop, and found some recommended drivers. This resulted in crash. I then downloaded Driver Booster and installed drivers through that, which also resulted in crash.

I'm not sure but I think I installed a BIOS update the first time i reinstalled Windows 10. The update came from Lenovo's site.

First time I reinstalled Windows through an external HDD, the Windows installation wouldn't let me install Windows 10 on the SSD after i erased the disk: "Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style". I found a guide and used cmd and diskpart, which allowed me to install Windows 10.

If I remember correctly (can't find the information since they updated their site), a "technician" from the retailer that sold me the laptop, had put inside a SSD. I'm not sure if there was a HDD before, since they decided to replace it.

**Computer information**

Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd Gen 20BS

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20Ghz (4 CPUs), 2.2Ghz

Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500

8192MB RAM

256GB SSD

Phoenix BIOS SC-T v2.1

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Which device drivers specifically cause this problem?

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: I don't know which drives cause the problem, since the drivers download simultaneously and install right after each other. I tried to make a restore point, but Windows  couldn't find any of the saved restore points when it crashed. With the restore point, I hoped I could restore Windows 10 and then one by one, find which driver crashed my system. magicandre1981:

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know about the minidump files up until now. Since I reinstalled the system, and haven't had any BSOD since, I can't find the folder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user reinstalled the system and the question is obsolete.